# xframe_options_exempt for enabling iframe not working in django

Tags: python, django, iframe, http-headers, x-frame-options

I am currently trying to load an iframe in Django within Facebook messenger following the official guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions

I have whitelisted the domain I am trying to load in the iframe.

I am using

- Django version 1.11.3
- plain vanilla Django folder structure
- ngrok for testing my application

in my settings.py file I have under middleware

```
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

my view.py file looks like this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

@xframe_options_exempt
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'template5.html')
```

Replacing my function return to

```
return HttpResponse("some text")
```

won't help.

The decorator is specified in the django documentation for allowing iframes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/clickjacking/

my urls.py file looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', view.login, name='login'),
]
```

However, iframe won't open in desktop browsers. Also removing 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', from settings.py doesn't help

Comment: later on this very same setup worked out! still not sure what caused the problem before. Maybe FB Messenger platform related!